# Yeoman scaffold (angular/requirejs/coffeescript) test failed

Tags: javascript, angularjs, coffeescript, requirejs, yeoman

I wanted to create a scaffold for my new JS-based web application using Yeoman. I want the scaffold to support:

- angular.js
- requirejs
- twitter bootstrap
- coffeeScript
- compass

But unfortunately I couldn't find generator, that has all these features. `generator-angular`, when invoked with `--coffee` option has everything but require.js and `generator-angular-require` has everything but ignores `--coffee` option...

So I made one scaffold using `generator-angular`, another one using `generator-angular-require` and used directory comparison tool to merge them together. Resulting scaffold is in my repository: https://github.com/mnowotka/chembl_cloud. This seems to work fine but unfortunately tests fail:

```
grunt test

...

Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.9 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/mnt/solr_index/cloud/chembl_cloud/app/scripts/*.js" were excluded.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/mnt/solr_index/cloud/chembl_cloud/test/mock/**/*.coffee" does not match any file.
WARN [watcher]: All files matched by "/mnt/solr_index/cloud/chembl_cloud/app/scripts/**/*.js" were excluded.
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "/mnt/solr_index/cloud/chembl_cloud/test/spec/**/*.js" does not match any file.
INFO [PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux)]: Connected on socket D-EIUNHEHXRkv_cCziCT
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux) ERROR
    Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (angular, MainCtrl) {
      return angular.module('chemblCloudApp', ['chemblCloudApp.controllers.MainCtrl', 'ngCookies', 'ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']).config(function($routeProvider) {
        return $routeProvider.when('/', {
          templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
          controller: 'MainCtrl'
        }).otherwise({
          redirectTo: '/'
        });
      });
    }
    http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#mismatch
    at /mnt/solr_index/cloud/chembl_cloud/node_modules/requirejs/require.js:141
PhantomJS 1.9.7 (Linux): Executed 0 of 0 ERROR (0.186 secs / 0 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

I've spent some time on this issue but I can't figure out what is wrong, this is my first scaffold using yeoman and I don't have much experience, please help.

Comment: Did you follow the link to the requirejs.org site that you got in your error message and read what it says there?

Comment: @Louis - yes I did, but I guess I don't understand the answer well enough to solve my problem...

Comment: Same problem w/o requirejs